# Apache2 proxy_fcgi:error AH01071: Got error ‘Primary script unkown’

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2

I recive a lot of Errors in my Apache2 Error Logs that says:

`[Thu Dec 02 08:07:33.164090 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9590:tid 140652906006272] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown`

The System is:

Ubuntu 20.04

Apache 2.4.41

PHP  8.0.13

Any idea what it caused and how to solve this?

Comment: Share your apache config.

Comment: Its just the Default-Config. Anything i changed is: 
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600

Answer (score 1):

*In my case, I'm getting this error when accessing a `/wp-includes/blocks/` that contains a `index.php` (some bot scan trying to extract info from wordpress)*

On [this answer at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/1108226/51689), I saw they add `<If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">` to the apache vhost config, like

```
# /etc/apache2/conf-available/php8.1-fpm.conf
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Adding that `<If>` makes apache now be more specific with the error log regarding undefined PHP constants.

Maybe this helps to find the source of the problem.